# Fastest reinstall of IBM i on AS/400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a iSeries that I am using for learning. Because it is for learning, I continually mess it up and end up having to reinstall the OS. This is a highly time consuming process, mainly because I have to babysit the machine as it asks for more disks (9+). I'm trying to figure out a more speedy process to reinstall the OS. This is my current approach:

1. Reinstall LMC (Optical media)
2. Reinstall OS (Optical media)
3. Install minimal LICPGMs (QSYS, etc.)
4. Create image catalog, load from IFS
5. Install remaining LICPGM

Running 7.2 of a 8203-E4A with DVD and Tape drives. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

- After a known good install with all PTFs applied, to a `GO SAVE` followed by a *21*. This creates a tape you can IPL from and restore the system to it's last state.
- You could install a primary IBM i LPAR as Hypervisor (to not mess up with) and host a second one within to mess up with. When your secondary install has a known good state, shut it down and simply create a tar or *SAVF from the virtual disk files in */QFPNWSSTG'. If you need to restore, delete the storage files, unpack the old ones, reapply to the *NWSD and go again.

Answer (score 1):

what are you doing to wreak the box?  Sound like you are wiping and starting from scratch...is that really necessary?  If the box IPLs, you should be able to re-install from an image catalog automatically.  [Replacing software using the automatic installation method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahc/usingautoinstall.htm)

Comment: I have had issues with getting TELNET, and Navigator (HTTP Server) in general to work. I assume these should work out of the box, so I assumed I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any TCP/IP services (including Telnet), you need 5770-TC1 - IBM TCP/IP Connectivity Utilities for i. If you want the HTTP server you need 5770-DG1 - IBM HTTP Server for i, and with both of these it may be necessary to have PASE installed which is 5770-SS1 option 33.

To use Navigator, that is part of IBM i Access, and you need 5770-XE1 and 5770-XW1, and also 5770-SS1 option 12 which is host servers.

For all of these you need to make sure you install the latest PTF cume tape. If you only install the base OS without PTF's you will get a lot of weird bugs.